# SELECT FROM WHERE char column with mixed string and integers values throwing conversion failed converting varchar to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't found a question similar to mine, probably because I'm not even sure how to ask it, but I have this table, with several columns, many of them of type `char(4)`.

The column with the issue has values like these:

```
|PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06|
|--------------------|
|FNCY|
|   2|
|   3|
|GRN |
|STD |
|    |
|COMB|
|   1|
|CHO |
```

So, when I do: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=109faa9d55c9a8926e7e3f19767518c1)

```
SELECT RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
FROM Table1 RPO
INNER JOIN Table2 PM ON PM.PRODUCT = RPO.PRODUCT
WHERE RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER = '00012122'
GROUP BY RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.COMMODITY, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES01, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
```

I get:

```
|REFERENCE_NUMBER   |PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06|
|-------------------|--------------------|
|00012122           |1                   |
|00012122           |3                   |
|00012122           |GRN                 |
```

BUT when I do: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9b0f28ee40658e7cd5aebcac9bf26722)

```
SELECT RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
FROM Table1 RPO
INNER JOIN Table2 PM ON PM.PRODUCT = RPO.PRODUCT
WHERE PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06 = 1 
  AND RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER = '00012122'
GROUP BY RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.COMMODITY, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES01, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
```

It tries to convert GRN to `int` and throws this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'GRN ' to data type int.

I have tried using the `CHAR` function, but I'm just shooting in the dark, I don't really know what to do.

I know the design is bad, buy I didn't do this, and also, I cannot change it.

How can I fix the query?

**EDIT Added fiddle links**

or try:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [REFERENCE_NUMBER] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PRODUCT] [char](12) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [Table2](
    [PRODUCT] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06] [char](4) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Table1 (REFERENCE_NUMBER, PRODUCT) VALUES ('REF1','PRODUCT1') 
INSERT INTO Table1 (REFERENCE_NUMBER, PRODUCT) VALUES ('REF1','PRODUCT2')
INSERT INTO Table1 (REFERENCE_NUMBER, PRODUCT) VALUES ('REF1','PRODUCT3')

INSERT INTO Table2 (PRODUCT, PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06) VALUES ('PRODUCT1',1)
INSERT INTO Table2 (PRODUCT, PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06) VALUES ('PRODUCT2',2)
INSERT INTO Table2 (PRODUCT, PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06) VALUES ('PRODUCT3','GRN')

--works without product category on where
SELECT RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
FROM Table1 RPO
INNER JOIN Table2 PM ON PM.PRODUCT = RPO.PRODUCT
WHERE RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER = 'REF1'
GROUP BY RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06

-- doesn't work, this error I'm trying to find a solution
SELECT RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
FROM Table1 RPO
INNER JOIN Table2 PM ON PM.PRODUCT = RPO.PRODUCT
WHERE PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06 = 1
AND RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER = 'REF1'
GROUP BY RPO.REFERENCE_NUMBER, PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06
```

Comment: WHERE PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06 = '1'

Comment: Why do you always have those `GROUP BY` clauses when you're never using any aggregation functions (`AVG`, `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`) in your queries? That's totally useless....

Comment: Sorry @marc_s, they slipped, my complete query does uses SUM for other columns, I just tried to keep it simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06 = 1
```

Makes SQL Server attempt to convert all values to an int, because `1` unquoted is an int. Correct it to a string, since your column data is a string:

```
PM.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES06 = '1'
```

And it works.

Comment: I did try this before asking the question, but it doesn't work on MS SQL Server Management Studio, but I see it works on the fiddle. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Most like something is more complicated with your real life situation. I was running this in SSMS.

Comment: By It doesn't work on MS SQL Server Management Studio, I mean it doesn't throw any results.

Comment: Gonna mark this as an answer, but I ended up using WHERE isnumeric(column) = 1 AND column = 1, after 1 complete day of dealing with this, this solution just came to my mind.

Comment: @Lauro182 you really don't want to be doing that though, because you are causing SQL Server loads more work, first it has to compare every row in the database to see if its a numeric value, so indexes are out the window. Then it is implicitly converting the datatype instead of comparing as a native datatype.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I know about this. I'm actually creating a couple of temp tables from previous date range filter, to work with a lot less information and using only what I need. I know it not as efficient, but it will have to do.

Comment: @Lauro182 Also `ISNUMERIC` has a lot of issues, you are better off using `TRY_CAST`